# 'last -d' is REALLY slow

Tags: last

I can run the command `last` (and `last -i`) in a fraction of a second, but when I run `last -d`, [according to my tests](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/e98af93a80da90d0152b), it takes a whopping 5 minutes and 22 seconds.

Just for reference, this is what adding the `-d` flag does:

> ```
>    -d     For non-local logins, Linux stores not only the host name of the
>           remote host but its IP number as well.  This  option  translates
>           the IP number back into a hostname.
> ```

There is no indication in the man pages that it should take that much extra amount of time. As it says, Linux stores the IP already, so it shouldn't have to do any sort of slow reverse-lookup of the IP based on the hostname on the spot. In addition, it is slow even when it is "looking up" that the hostname value of `:0` (a local login) should return the "IP address" value of `0.0.0.0`.

Is the `-d` flag slow on all computers, or just mine? Could this indicate a corrupted file somewhere which may be inaccessible or difficult to read?

*For reference, I am running **32-bit Ubuntu 13.10** (haven't upgraded yet).*

Comment: My tests are with `-d` `real, user, time (0m0.282s, 0m0.010s, 0m0.039s)` vs without  `real, user, time (0m0.005s, 0m0.000s, 0m0.008s)`. So it's not affecting my pc.

Comment: @polym Thanks for checking. What distribution are you running?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy) 64 bit

Comment: How long does `last -i` take?

Comment: And btw, in my system also there is no time lag. It displays the results as soon as I issue the command.

Comment: @Ramesh `last -i` takes `0.007s` (virtually instant).

Comment: @IQAndreas, try pinging the IP of one of the output from `last -i` command and check if the host is reachable. I suspect it should be something related to `nslookup`.

Comment: @Ramesh All four hosts in the list (`0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1`, my home IP, and my work IP) are reachable via `ping` (though my work IP takes about 47ms to reach).

Comment: can you get the source of `last` command ( via `apt-get source sysvinit-utils` ), write some test debug prints and look, where its taking forever? I guess it's taking forever at the `getnameinfo` call, but I might be wrong.

Comment: `strace last -d`

Comment: @Creek https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/ed534b0ef97631b0c136 It "hangs" right at that `read(4,` part. If I wait, it continues after a few seconds and writes a bit of data, then hangs at a `read(4` again. Let me know if you want the full output, instead of just up until the part where it hangs.

Comment: @IQAndreas there's a `connect` to `8.8.8.8` then `/var/run/avahi-daemon/socket` then `write(4, "RESOLVE-ADDRESS 0.0.0.0\n", 24)` then the pause.  Looks like @garethTheRed is on the right track, DNS resolution is getting stuck on 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 3):

What's the DNS search order in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`? It should have `files` as the first option:-

```
hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

It might be worth confirming the search order in your system.

I carried out the same test and had a result of 47 seconds for `last -d`.

I then added `0.0.0.0 localhost` to `/etc/hosts` and it now take a mere 0.031s to run `last -d`.

Note - I've removed the `0.0.0.0` since, as [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0), it's not valid to have it there.

Comment: I haven't modified the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file, so the `hosts` setting is using the Ubuntu default value of `files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`. Although I have modified `/etc/hosts`, the line `0.0.0.0 localhost` is still there as per the defaults.

Comment: What are you getting in the third column of the output of `last -d`?  Is it `0.0.0.0` or `localhost`?

Comment: I'm an idiot, I glanced and I could have sworn I saw `0.0.0.0` in the hosts file, but I checked again _properly_, and it wasn't there.

Comment: You are correct, adding the line to `/etc/hosts` speeds `last -d` up to a whopping `0.018s`! Could you add a link to what you mean by "according to Wikipedia"?

Comment: I was going by the first sentence of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

Comment: I did think it was odd that you said that the line `0.0.0.0 localhost` is still there **as per the defaults**.  But as I'm not running Ubuntu, I couldn't argue!