# Where does 'last' store user hostnames?

Tags: last

I was looking into: 'last -d' command.

```
-d: For non-local logins, Linux stores not only the host name of the remote host but its IP number as well. This option translates the IP number back into a hostname.
```

At first, I was looking at similar questions, This one in particular:
['last -d' is REALLY slow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138985/last-d-is-really-slow/139001#139001)

Before I updated my hosts file and added: 0.0.0.0 localhost I received less hostnames and more IP addresses. So that means Linux stores the hostnames somewhere in the OS, If that's the case, is there any way of reaching the hostnames without the command `last -d`?

Comment: `man` page of `last` states this: `Last` searches back through the file `/var/log/wtmp` (or the  file  designated  by  the -f flag) and displays a list of all users logged in (and out) since that file was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `man last`, my Arch Linux system stores login info in `/var/log/wtmp`. It looks to be in a [binary format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp#utmp.2C_wtmp_and_btmp) - that is, the usual text tools will only show you parts of it.

This command: `xxd /var/log/wtmp | more` shows me both text-format dotted-quad IP addresses, and fully-qualified DNS names.

I wrote the following little program to show me what was in `/var/log/utmp`. It appears that not every entry has a hostname/IP address, and that the binary format only has a small, fixed amount of room for the hostname.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmp.h>

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
        struct utmp *utmpp;
        utmpname("/var/log/wtmp");
        while (NULL != (utmpp = getutent())) {
                printf("%s\n", utmpp->ut_host);
        }
        endutent();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think if you check utmpp->ut_type == USER_PROCESS every entry has address or hostname.